# How auto refetch react-query's useQuery for dynamic query function

Tags: reactjs, react-query, web3-react

I am trying to use useQuery for smart contract interaction.

The problem is, the `contract` return from `useContract` is null initially, as `library` and `chainId` are null initially.

So, the first fetch from `useQuery` is using a `null contract` to call the `fetchPaginated` function. Even `library` and `chainId` got initialised such that `contract` is not null, the `useQuery` does not get refetched.

The `contract` is a complex object that can't be set as query keys.

How to trigger the refetch for this kind of dynamic query function in `useQuery`?

Below are the codes:

```
// hook for handling contract
export function useContract<T extends Contract = Contract>(
  address: string,
  ABI: any,
  withSignerIfPossible = true,
): T | null {
  const { library, account, chainId } = useWeb3React();

  return useMemo(() => {
    if (!address || !ABI || !library || !chainId) return null;
    try {
      return getContract(
        address,
        ABI,
        library,
        withSignerIfPossible && account ? account : undefined,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to get contract', error);
      return null;
    }
  }, [address, ABI, library, chainId, withSignerIfPossible, account]) as T;
}

// The useQuery that want to get refetched
export const useFetchERC20Contracts = (
  page: number,
  pageSize: number,
) => {
  const contract = useContract();

  const result = useQuery<Response>(
    ['contract', page, pageSize],
    async () => {
      if (!contract) {
        return [];
      }
      return contract.fetchPaginated(page, pageSize);
    },
    { cacheTime: 0 },
  );

  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything that the queryFn depends on and that should drive the query to re-fetch should go into the query key. If you can't put `contract` there for some reason, you have to add its dependencies, in this case:

```
address, ABI, library, chainId, withSignerIfPossible, account
```

generally, I wouldn't separate this into two hooks. I would just have the queryFn call `getContract` directly, because that makes the dependencies obvious.